# Compare equality of two Cursor objects

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to implement a JUnit test for a method which creates and returns a `Cursor` object from an `Image` object when moving the mouse wheel. The idea is to load a different cursor each time moving the mouse wheel:

```
public void testMouseWheelMoved() {

    MouseWheelEvent e = new MouseWheelEvent(aJPanel, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, 0, 0, 0);

    for (String iconName : myListenerClass.getIconNames()) {

        myListenerClass.mouseWheelMoved(e);
        Cursor currentViewCursor = aJPanel.getCursor();

        assertEquals(currentViewCursor, myListenerClass.getCursorForIcon(iconName));
    }
}
```

`getCursorForIcon` returns a `Cursor` object. `myListenerClass` is an instance of a class implementing `MouseWheelListener`. `aJPanel` is an instance of a class extending `JPanel`.

```
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

    // ...

    String iconName = this.iconNames.get(0); // returns icon name at index 0
    this.view.setCursor(this.getCursorForIcon(iconName));

}
```

`this.view` is `aJPanel` from above.

Unfortunately this test (`assertEquals`) always fails even though both compared `Cursor` objects should be identical.

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.awt.Cursor` does not implement `equals()` so it delegates to Object equals which will only return true if the reference is the same.

Therefore you have to implement you own equals method using whatever object information you decide is "equal" for your code.

```
 Cursor currentViewCursor = aJPanel.getCursor();

 assertCursorsEquals(currentViewCursor, myListenerClass.getCursorForIcon(iconName));

}

private void assertCursorsEquals( Cursor a, Cursor b){
  assertEquals(a.getType(), b.getType());
  ...//other checks you care about

}
```